maskedtextbox requires extra input to be able to return entered information
So I have masked textbox for russian phone number
7(999)000-00-00

For some reason it requires 11 inputs instead of 10 to return a value instead of null even so the last input won't be written into the box

Solved. For some reason Visual studio created an MaskInputRejected event for maskedtextbox by default instead of Text Changed.
